# debug apk on browser

Tags: debugging, browser, apk, temenos-quantum

I have an apk which is built on the KONY platform. I want to debug the apk by viewing the files on the browser to place debug points. I want to use a device farm platform such as pCloudy where I can link a device from the device farm to Kony.

Is this possible? I do not want to use a physical device or emulator from android studio. It has to be a device from a device farm like pCloudy.

I have tried pCloudy platform but was unable to debug the apk i.e viewing the files of the apk on a browser. Have also tried other platforms such as browserStack etc but do not have a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know from Kony products you can debug an Android build with Google Chrome, and an iOS build with Safari.

Below is the doc about debug a Kony Android build with Google Chrome :
https://docs.kony.com/7_3/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Content/Inline_Debugger.htm

Hoping this will help.

Cordially,
Hervé N.